# Read list using foreach get another result

Tags: c#

Why I have got this result?

Code:

```
List<int> samba = new List<int>(new int[]
            {1,2,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,
             0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
             });
  foreach (int i in samba)
            {
                label1.Text += samba[i];
            }
```

Result:

```
1201111002111111111
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you get that result?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I get correct answer from Servy I have to wait to agree his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you didn't mean to print out the item at the index of the current item, but rather, but rather the current item:

```
List<int> samba = new List<int>(new int[]
{1,2,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    });
foreach (int i in samba)
{
    label1.Text += i;
}
```

The first time through your loop you're printing out the item at position `1`, which is `2`.  The second time you're printing out the item at position `2`, which is `0`.  Then you print out the item at position `0` four times, and that's `1`, etc.

Comment: I had to read that over and over again before I figured out what he was doing!

Comment: @Servy Yes you have right, this shame for me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want:

```
label1.Text = string.Join("", samba);
label1.Text += string.Join("", samba); // if the leading 1 is correct
```

What you're doing:

```
for every value n in samba
  append the value represented at index=n in samba
```

Though I'm not sure about the leading 1 (I get `201111002111111111` when I run your code), so I'm guessing it's in `label1.Text` prior to this code getting executed.

Comment: This is what he already has. In a more verbose way.

Comment: @DanielBrückner:  No he doesn't.  He's mixing a `foreach` and a `for`.

Comment: @AustinSalonen sorry, didn't notice he use indexing. +1 for you